# Dots moving primarily in one direction rather than randomly

Tags: java

I am trying to write a Java version of [Code Bullet's AI tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOZfhUcNiqk) and while I've managed to build the JFrame and I get the dots to render properly, they are not behaving like expected.

For context, when the population of dots are initialized, they are initialized with a "brain" that is a random list of 1000 directions that tell them how to move at each step. These directions are generated by the following code:

```
//Further up they are initialized with 1000 as the argument
//Also, an int array called directions is an attribute
public Brain(int size){
  directions = new int[size];
  Random dir = new Random();
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    directions[i] = dir.nextInt(8);
  }
}
```

The reason 0 to 7 (inclusive) is generated is because the movement of the dots is coded as the following switch statement (where x and y are the dot's position on the grid:

```
switch (direction){ //Slightly simplified here.
  case 0: this.y--;
  case 1: this.y--; this.x++;
  case 2: this.x++;
  case 3: this.x++; this.y++;
  case 4: this.y++;
  case 5: this.y++; this.x--;
  case 6: this.x--;
  case 7: this.x--; this.y--;
}
```

In theory, as the directions are initialized randomly, the dots should move randomly all over the grid from their starting position. However, when I run the code, they all just move down and left. Can anyone help me? Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/Treldman/SmartDots/blob/master/SmartDots.java), with the relevant lines being 55-256. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No `break`! Your switch statement has no break statements anywhere, and so they won't work as you're expecting as all lines after the appropriate case statement are run. Please read the [Switch tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a `break` statement, execution continues with the next case block ...

As a result, case 7 is always executed, biasing the movement towards bottom left of the screen.

Comment: Ah, yep, that'd be it. It's been a while since I've worked with switch-case, thanks very much!